# Formatting text in header tag containing glyphicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am trying to format a news-feed item and want to include a glyphicon to illustrate the type of news item and then a user defined text field next to it.  I would like to have the text formatted such that it is indented about four spaces from the glyphicon (Second news feed item in the JSFiddle where I hardcoded it in a non-reproducible way).

I made a layout where the glyphicon was in a col-xs-1 and the rest of the screen was for the text and then zeroed out all the padding but it still too far to the right for what I would like (Third news feed item in the JSFiddle).

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 news-feed-item-container" style="background-color:white">
    <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>New conversation with Brett Harrsion from Firm XYZ shows there is progress being made towards the product approval</h3>
    <p class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1">There have been talks with the team at advisor group that lead us to believe we will be able to sell MLCDs sometime in early March</p>
  </div>


  <div class="col-xs-12 news-feed-divider-yellow"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 news-feed-item-container">
    <h3 style="white-space:pre"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>    New conversation with Brett Harrsion from Firm XYZ shows there<br>        is progress being made towards the product approval</h3>
    <p class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1">There have been talks with the team at Firm XYZ that lead us to believe we will be able to sell product A to them sometime in early March</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 news-feed-divider"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 news-feed-item-container" style="background-color:white">
    <div class="col-xs-1" style="padding-right:0">
      <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></h3></div>
    <div class="col-xs-11" style="padding-left:0">
      <h3>New conversation with Brett Harrsion from Firm XYZ shows there is progress being made towards the product approval</h3></div>
    <p class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1">There have been talks with the team at advisor group that lead us to believe we will be able to sell MLCDs sometime in early March</p>
  </div>
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/schins02/r0p83uaq/

Image of feed items with styles applied =>
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gqCN.jpg

This seems a bit picky so thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your needs, I would not recommend relying on `.col-*-*` for your positioning.  Your needs are simply below what Bootstrap's Grid framework is designed for.

Instead, I would rely on wrappers with `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` to position your icon and content.  I've created an example here:

http://www.bootply.com/LwfLZZ2exY

**Note**: My example makes use of `calc()` because I wasn't sure how responsive your design approach needed.  You may need to adjust this (and of course any other element) to best-suit your intentions.

Comment: This was just what I was looking for!  I am running into an odd problem that I'm afraid isn't going to yield any help. When running this code locally with Chrome this works just fine.  As soon as I push it out to staging, I get an invalid property value for the width/calc function.  I've been reading up on calc but this doesn't make any sense and I fear it won't to anyone else but I thought I'd just put it out there in case anyone had any ideas or had dealt with strange issues like this before.

Comment: If you're having another issue just make sure to post a new topic (after searching to see if it's already been addressed of course!)